# How to return a non-match in two 2d list?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have two 2d list with large amount of rows and different size length for both lists. I'm having trouble with finding match in each row in df1 and return only the non-matching values for each row in df2. For example, df1[0] has match of 1,3,5 in df2[0] return 17. df1[0] has no match in df2[1] return nothing or bracket. So on and so on for each row in df1 and df2.

I have tried these codes but doesn't give me what I desire.

```
no_matches = []
for sublist1 in df1:
    for sublist2 in df2:
        no_match = [val for val in sublist2 if val not in sublist1]
        if no_match: no_matches.append(no_match)
print("no matches:", no_matches)
```

Here a short example (My 2d list)

```
 df1 = [[1, 7, 3, 5], [2, 5, 14, 10]]
 df2 = [[1, 17, 3, 5], [34, 14, 74], [34, 3, 87], [25, 14, 10]]
```

Convert to 3d list.

```
 no_match = 0: [[17], [], [34,87], []]
            1: [[1,3,17], [34,74], [], [25]]
```

Possible Desire ( Convert into 2d list and remove brackets ) If possible

```
 no_match = [[17],[34,87],[1,3,17],[34,74],[25]]
```

Comment: What does "convert 3d list" do? How did you get that output? When I run your code, I get a 2D list. Output is `no matches: [[17], [34, 14, 74], [34, 87], [25, 14, 10], [1, 17, 3], [34, 74], [34, 3, 87], [25]]`. Please clarify.

Comment: Nothing Thought it will convert to 3d list.

Comment: How many times are you going to ask this question? I already showed you how to do this the last time you asked it.

Comment: You did but it wasn't the output I desire

Comment: So modify my answer to your needs. You got the results that you ASKED for. At what point do you become the programmer? You have people below giving you almost the exact same answers you got the last time you asked this question. On person giving you the "loop too much" way, and another giving you the `set` version. It's like dejavu in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use sets and its subtraction

```
df1 = [[1, 7, 3, 5], [2, 5, 14, 10]]
df2 = [[1, 17, 3, 5], [34, 14, 74], [34, 3, 87], [25, 14, 10]]

no_matches = []
for sublist1 in df1:
    set_1 = set(sublist1)
    for sublist2 in df2:
        set_2 = set(sublist2)
        no_match = list(set_2 - set_1)
        if no_match and len(no_match) != len(set_2):
            no_matches.append(no_match)

print("no matches:", no_matches)
```

Output: `no matches: [[17], [34, 87], [1, 3, 17], [34, 74], [25]]`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have an exception to the rule *"return only the non-matching values for each row in df2"*. In the example you describe that if *"df1[0] has no match in df2[1] return nothing"*, but this is contrary to the rule. If this is indeed an exception, then you need to add that exception to your `if` statement:

```
    if no_match and no_match != sublist2: 
        no_matches.append(no_match)
```

With this additional condition you'll get the desired output:

```
no matches: [[17], [34, 87], [1, 17, 3], [34, 74], [25]]
```

Comment: Question is the code supposed to be like this ```no_matches = []
for sublist1 in df1:
    for sublist2 in df2:
        # match = [val for val in sublist1 if val in sublist2]
        no_match = [val for val in sublist2 if val not in sublist1]
        # if match: matches.append(match)
        if no_match and no_matches != sublist2:
            no_matches.append(no_match)                         print("no matches:", no_matches)```

Comment: This is the output it giving me ```no matches: [[17], [34, 14, 74], [34, 87], [25, 14, 10], [1, 17, 3], [34, 74], [34, 3, 87], [25]]```

Comment: That's not the output I got: see it run on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma780884605459839#main.py)